# google map api returning identical results

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coldfusion

Can someone tell me why google map api v3 is returning identical results. Is this bug in api? I am having such issue when i geocode address as sydney.

I am using google map api in my coldfusion application where user inputs suburb and gets the nearest dealers around that area.

Comment: Thanks for posting a separate question! Now, to improve your question some more - can you possibly provide some (at least one) addresses that cause this issue? This would help others more knowledgeable in the topic to help further.

Comment: As this is tagged with ColdFusion, are you using CFMAP? It doesn't sound like it from the cursory infor you've provided, but if so, pls provide your code. Well, really: just provide your code anyhow!